# How would I refactor this code, using Presenters || Decorators || Poros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code works perfectly, however, I know my approach isn't best practice practice. I would appreciate the effort of anyone who tries to explain in details on how I could refactor this code using either(presenters, decorators or poros) - I have no deep understanding of either yet. 
Here is the code below:

In my events controller, I have a method called `tickets_report` defined as such

`def tickets_report 
    @all_bookings = @event.bookings
    @ticket_types = @event.ticket_types
    @attendees = @event.attendees 
  end`

then, I use the `@ticket_types` instance variable in my views to plot a table as follows:

```
<tbody>

<% grand_quantity = ticket_left = quantity_sold = total_price = total_amount = 0 %>
<% @tickets.each_with_index do |ticket, index| %> 
    <% remains = ticket.quantity.to_i - ticket.user_tickets.count.to_i 
       amount = ticket.price.to_f * ticket.user_tickets.count.to_i
       grand_quantity += ticket.quantity 
       ticket_left += remains 
       quantity_sold += ticket.user_tickets.count 
       total_price += ticket.price.to_f 
       total_amount += amount 
    %>
    <tr>
            <td><%= index + 1%></td>
            <td><%= ticket.name %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.quantity %></td>
            <td><%= remains %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.user_tickets.count %></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(ticket.price)%></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(amount)%></td>
          </tr>

<% end %> 
 <tr class="gtotal">  
    <td colspan="2">Grand Total</td>
    <td><%= grand_quantity %></td>
    <td><%= ticket_left %></td>
    <td><%= quantity_sold %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(total_price)%></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(total_amount)%></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

My problem is that calculations done in the view is really not a good thing, and this is how far I have gone trying to fix this myself

```
module Events
  class Ticket
    def initialize(ticket)
      @ticket = ticket
    end 

    def name 
      @ticket.name 
    end 

    def quantity 
      @ticket.quantity 
    end 

    def price 
      @ticket.price.to_f 
    end 

    def user_count 
      @ticket.user_tickets.count.to_i 
    end 

    def remains 
      @ticket.quantity.to_i - user_count 
    end 

    def amount 
      price  * user_count 
    end 
  end 

  class TicketReportPresenter < Ticket 
    @@grand_quantity = @@ticket_left = @@quantity_sold = 0 
    @@total_price = @@total_amount = 0 

    def initialize(ticket)
      @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket)
      @@grand_quantity += @ticket.quantity.to_i  
      @@ticket_left += @ticket.remains 
      @@quantity_sold += @ticket.user_count 
      @@total_price += @ticket.price 
      @@total_amount ++ @ticket.amount 
    end 

    class << self 

      def grand_quantity 
        @@grand_quantity
      end 

      def ticket_left 
        @@ticket_left 
      end 

      def quantity_sold 
        @@quantity_sold
      end 

      def total_price 
        @@total_price
      end 

      def total_amount 
        @@total_amount 
      end 
    end    
  end
end
```

The new `tickets_report` method in my controller

`def tickets_report 
    @all_bookings = @event.bookings
    @ticket_types = Events::TicketReportPresenter.new(@event.ticket_types.first)
    @attendees = @event.attendees 
 end`

However, things don't seem to be going right at this point. For instance I cannot call ActiveRecord relationships on the tickets object I defined. What is the best approach to refactor the logic present in the view, a detailed description and source code will suffice plus links to other resources. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is more of a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @BryanSaxon thanks, I just moved it over there

Comment: Sure thing Damian!

Comment: [Here it is on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128316/displaying-information-about-a-ticket-purchase)

Comment: This question has been answered. Please find the answer [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128316/displaying-information-about-a-ticket-purchase)